# How to hide controls in Access Report

Tags: ms-access

[access report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdCQE.jpg)

[access query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DpPj.jpg)

I am trying to set the reprt to display period 7 but i am having problems cos the calculated field then dont work. Is there a way to hide period 6 and still select period 7 to display.

Comment: A field in the query builder has a *Display* checkBox, and a control in a report has a `Visible` property.You can set these to `True` or `False` Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Hallo Marian. The problem i am having is that in the future(6mths) from now the report is going to be a lenghty one. I need to select the period i want the report to display. But since the calculated fields are there they wont give the right calculation.

Comment: click on the report above and you will see that the period is 6 or seven. IF I select 7 then all calculated columns in the report are blank. How can i hide it in the report so that the calculated fields continue in the background.

Comment: Actually i want to hide the rows where period is 7. I tried on query but then the result shows 7 but all calculated fields are 0